# Apache Solr for single database column suggestions

Tags: java, database, solr, lucene, autocorrect

I have a relational database with few tables. Some of them have columns that I want to enable autocompletion / autocorrection on (e.g. titles, tags, categories).

I have seen that [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which builds upon Lucene indexing can offer such functionality. Also data [can be fed](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) in to Solr from relational database.

My question is: is this the best way I can get autocomplete and autocorrect services for my entities? Or am I killing a mosquito with a bazooka here?

Solr requires a lot of resources, memory and stuff and I wonder if something far simpler can do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

How many unique values do you have in title, tags , categories? A few thousand? Then I think you can get away with using a Trie Data structure. A few million records in those columns? Then Solr / Elasticsearch might be good option.

I have used Trie for autosuggestion. Building a Trie is expensive. But you can store the trie in Memcached or even SQL and update it periodically when new data is added to your columns.

Comment: Try is good for autocomplete, but i also would need to implement a structure good on autocorrection for tge second task.

Comment: You can use trie for spell check also. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21367876/689625 , http://www.techniful.in/2012/04/spell-checker-using-trie_3.html . You can also use a dedicated spell checker - http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html . You can use the words from your sql column as input to this spell checker.